# Unable to reset Parse user's password when using email address as username

Tags: ios, parse-platform

According to the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-resetting/iOS), a password reset request will check the username **and** email address fields:

> This will attempt to match the given email with the user's email or
>   username field, and will send them a password reset email. By doing
>   this, you can opt to have users use their email as their username, or
>   you can collect it separately and store it in the email field.

However, when I attempt this I am receiving

`[Error]: invalid email address (Code: 125, Version: 1.6.2)`

To be clear, I am collecting a valid email address from the user and storing it as the username as per the instructions. I am requesting the reset using:

```
[PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:theEmailAddress
                                               block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                                   if (!error)
                                                   {
                                                       [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Reset Successful" message:@"Check your email to complete the password reset process."];
                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
                                                       NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
                                                       [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Reset Failed" message:errorString];
                                                   }
                                               }];
```

Is anybody else currently able to get this to work?

Comment: We're experiencing the same bug right now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the email part of an account within the "User" class?

If not, that would be your problem. The fact that your getting an invalid email error is telling me that either the user does not exist or the variable you are using to store the email, `theEmailAddress` is not correct.

**UPDATE:**

So the code below works for me. Sorry that it is in Swift but I think you should be able to get the idea of whats going on.

I ask the user to input their username in another View Controller and then I retrieve the email using that info...the circumstances for my app do not allow for the user to input their email, I have to ask them for their username first.).

Probably also important to note that I'm using an older version of the Parse SDK so it might be a bug with the version your using. Also, Parse released an update yesterday so it might be worth downloading it to see if it changes anything.

```
 PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("checkAccountStatus", withParameters: ["username" : username, "operation" : 2]) {
        (answer: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

                self.email = answer[3] as String!

                PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(self.email){
                    (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    if (success == true) {

                        let emailAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Password Reset", message: "An email containing information on how to reset your password has been sent to " + self.email + ".", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        let emailCancel = UIAlertAction (title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

                        emailAlert.addAction(emailCancel)

                        self.presentViewController(emailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a PFUser. And if I purposely send an incorrect email address (one with no matching record stored in the user table) I actually get a different, more specific error - so I can rule that out.

Comment: Can you provide the "more specific error" please? :)

Comment: And can you upload some more code so I can get a better idea of what's going on? :)

Comment: The more specific error when a username isn't found is "no user found with email <blablabla> (Code: 205, Version: 1.6.2)". I don't have any more code.

Comment: Looked into it a bit: 1) Are there any capitals in the email? 2) Are you absolutely sure the email is valid/is a string and your not passing an empty variable?

Comment: Checked these both but no dice, sorry. Would a demo project help? I could set up a separate Parse app and connect it up to that.

Comment: I'm currently working on adding a password reset feature to my app so once I get that done, if mine works, I'll let you know. :)

Comment: I just took a second look a realized that your missing the @ symbol. I don't know much of obj-c (I use Swift) but don't you need that in front of the variable?

Comment: Hey, so I got my reset password working. Like I said, I only know Swift.